# Populating an inventory UI with JSON, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, json, database, list, unity-game-engine

I'm using JSON and LitJSON in Unity 5 to populate an inventory UI for a game. The problem is, my code is not returning anything except for information from the item at id:0. At this point I just have two items in my JSON. My code in Unity will recognize that there are only items at id:0 and id:1, because if I put anything else in there, I get an error outside of the argument, but it's still only printing information to the console for id:0.

Here is my JSON:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Stun Gun",
        "value": 6,
        "stats": {
            "power": 100,
            "defense": 4,
            "vitality": 2
        },
        "description": "Testing the Stun Gun.",
        "stackable": false,
        "rarity": 2,
        "slug": "stun_gun"
    },

    {
    "id": 1,
        "title": "The Great Gun",
        "value": 500,
        "stats": {
            "power": 700,
            "defense": 10,
            "vitality": 10
        },
        "description": "The Great Gun is great.",
        "stackable": true,
        "rarity": 6,
        "slug": "the_great_gun"
    }
]
```

Here is my Inventory script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject inventoryPanel;
    GameObject slotPanel;
    ItemDatabase database;
    public GameObject inventorySlot;
    public GameObject inventoryItem;

    int slotAmount;
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    public List<GameObject> slots = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start ()
    {
        database = GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();

        slotAmount = 8;
        inventoryPanel = GameObject.Find ("Inventory Panel");
        slotPanel = inventoryPanel.transform.FindChild ("Slot Panel").gameObject;
        for (int i = 0; i < slotAmount; i++) 
        {
            items.Add(new Item());
            slots.Add(Instantiate(inventorySlot));
            slots[i].transform.SetParent(slotPanel.transform);
        }

        AddItem(0);
        AddItem(1);

        Debug.Log(items[1].Slug);
    }

    public void AddItem (int id)
    {
        Item itemToAdd = database.FetchItemByID(id);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (items[i].ID == -1)
            {
                items[i] = itemToAdd;
                GameObject itemObj = Instantiate(inventoryItem);
                itemObj.transform.SetParent(slots[i].transform);
                itemObj.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
                itemObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = itemToAdd.Sprite;
                itemObj.name = itemToAdd.Title;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ItemDatabase script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<Item> database = new List<Item>();
    private JsonData itemData;

    void Start ()
    {
        itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.json"));
        ConstructItemDatabase();

        Debug.Log (FetchItemByID(0).Description);
    }

    public Item FetchItemByID (int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
            if(database[id].ID == id)
                return database[i];
        return null;
    }

    void ConstructItemDatabase ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemData.Count; i++) 
        {
            database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["id"], itemData[i]["title"].ToString(), (int)itemData[i]["value"],
                (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["power"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["defense"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["vitality"], 
                itemData[i]["description"].ToString(), (bool)itemData[i]["stackable"], (int)itemData[i]["rarity"], 
                itemData[i]["slug"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int Vitality { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Stackable { get; set; }
    public int Rarity { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public Sprite Sprite { get; set; }

    public Item (int id, string title, int value, int power, int defense, int vitality, string description, bool stackable, int rarity, string slug)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Power = power;
        this.Vitality = vitality;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Stackable = stackable;
        this.Rarity = rarity;
        this.Slug = slug;
        this.Sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Items/" + slug);
    }

    public Item ()
    {
        this.ID = -1;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the correct number of slots, and the correct number of filled versus empty slots (2), but both slots are filled with the "stun_gun". Any help would be much appreciated. I'm new to Unity/C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
public Item FetchItemByID (int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
        if(database[i].ID == id)  // i rather than id
            return database[i];
    return null;
}
```